# UPDATE (B) from (A) if (B) = 0?

Tags: mysql

I'm learning this for school and I'm confused. I'm trying to copy information between columns in a single table in a single db, all local.

Basically:

(I need to loop through and update all records)

```
UPDATE `my_records` 
SET `realname` = `name` 
WHERE `realname` = 0;

SELECT * FROM `my_records` SET `realname` = `name` WHERE `realname` = 0;
```

It keeps telling me I have a syntax error.

I now see why they are asking me to learn this. Each row in the table is different so when I update all columns some rows change that shouldn't so that's not the end result I'm after. I can try to give an example but this is confusing to me.

DB -> Table -> Row 1 - holds the name of the person -> Row 2 - holds the picture
of the person

- Both things have a name (example Row 1 David, Row 2 Flower.JPG)

So I'm guessing they want me to figure out a way to exclude updating the 'real_name' column on Row 2 where the image is a JPG, GIF, or PNG.

I think the final result they are looking for when the table is updated is:

Row 1 'David' 'David'
Row 2 'flower.jpg'

Then this loops over and over again for all the records.

Comment: You wrote the correct `update` statement in your question.  If that's pseudo code, you should have tried it...

Comment: Can you check if you are using correct data type for realname as per what i think you are passing integer and it can be of different datatype.

Comment: Assuming `name` is a field in the table, it is a mysql reserved keyword so would need to be in backticks ie `\`realname\` = \`name\``. See the full list https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html

Comment: All good information which showed me I need to edit my original question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an `UPDATE` instead of a `SELECT`.  `SELECT` statements only return data, they do not modify data.

So, to return the records you will update in the next step:

```
SELECT `realname`, `name` FROM `my_records` WHERE `realname` = 0;
```

and then to update those records:

```
UPDATE `my_records` SET `realname` = `name` WHERE `realname` = 0;
```

Note that this query will update the entire table, setting any row where the value of `realname` is equivalent to `0`, to the value of that same row's `name` column.

A few other possibly useful statements:

```
UPDATE `my_records` SET `realname` = `name` WHERE `realname` = '';
```

This will affect all rows where `realname` is equivalent to 'empty string'

```
UPDATE `my_records` SET `realname` = `name` WHERE `realname` IS NULL;
```

will affect all rows where `realname` is `NULL`

Comment: Based on your answer I had to edit my original question. Thank you.